# How can I set a font from PSNFSS distribution families as the main math font?

Tags: amsmath, font-encodings, mathspec, math-fonts, mathastext

The declaration `\DeclareMathAlphabet{cmd}{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}` works to create a new command whose argument would be a font as specified in the declaration. PSNFSS distribution families work with it.

However, I want to get a simple way to declare global math fonts using the following code

```
\usepackage[]{mathspec}

        \newcommand{\mainmathfont}{TeX Gyre Termes}
        \setmathsfont(Latin)[]{\mainmathfont}
        \setmathsfont(Greek)[]{\mainmathfont}
        \setmathsfont(Digits)[]{\mainmathfont}
```

But it looks like it works only for `TeX Gyre`, `Courier`, and `Computer Modern` font families. How can I modify the commands above to globally customize math fonts?

Here is my source code

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}


\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}

\usepackage[]{mathspec}

        \newcommand{\mainmathfont}{TeX Gyre Termes}
        \setmathsfont(Latin)[]{\mainmathfont}
        \setmathsfont(Greek)[]{\mainmathfont}
        \setmathsfont(Digits)[]{\mainmathfont}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]}{\left(\substack{{x_{i, i+1}^{i^{2}}} \\ \\ {\left[ \frac{i+3}{3} \right]}}\right)}
    \frac{\sqrt{\mu(i)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left( i^{2} - 1 \right)}}{\sqrt[3]{\rho(i)-2} + \sqrt[3]{\rho(i)-1}} \Omega
\end{equation}

\[
\int_{\mathcal{D}} | \overline{\partial u} |^{2}
\Phi_{0}(z) e^{\alpha |z|^2}
\geq c_{4} \alpha \int_{\mathcal{D}} |u|^{2}\Phi_{0}
e^{\alpha |z|^{2}}
+ c_{5} \delta^{-2} \int_{A} |u|^{2}
\Phi_{0} e^{\alpha |z|^{2}}
\]

$\alpha \medspace \beta \medspace \gamma \medspace \delta \medspace \epsilon \medspace \varepsilon \medspace \zeta \medspace \eta \medspace \theta \medspace \vartheta \medspace \iota \medspace \kappa \medspace \lambda \medspace \mu \medspace \nu \medspace \xi \medspace \pi \medspace \sigma \medspace \varsigma \tau \medspace \upsilon \medspace \phi \medspace \varphi \medspace \chi \medspace \psi \medspace \omega \medspace \Delta \medspace \Xi \medspace \Phi \medspace \Omega \medspace \Psi$

$[1], \thinspace [2], \thinspace [3], \thinspace [4], \thinspace [5], \thinspace [6], \thinspace [7], \thinspace [8], \thinspace [9]$

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{A} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, 1}} {\varphi_{1} \times
                \varepsilon_{1}} & (x + \varepsilon_{2})^{2}
            & \cdots & (x + \varepsilon_{n - 1})^{n - 1}
            & (x + \varepsilon_{n})^{n}\\[10pt]
            \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, 1}} {\varphi_{2} \times
                \varepsilon_{1}} & \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, 2}}
            {\varphi_{2} \times \varepsilon_{2}} & \cdots &
            (x + \varepsilon_{n - 1})^{n - 1}
            & (x + \varepsilon_{n})^{n}\\
            \hdotsfor{5}\\
            \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, 1}} {\varphi_{n} \times
                \varepsilon_{1}} & \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, 2}}
            {\varphi_{n} \times \varepsilon_{2}} & \cdots
            & \dfrac{\varphi \cdot X_{n, n - 1}} {\varphi_{n}
                \times \varepsilon_{n - 1}} &
            \dfrac{\varphi\cdot X_{n, n}}
            {\varphi_{n} \times \varepsilon_{n}}
        \end{pmatrix}
    + \mathbf{I}_{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I = I_{ ph } -  
\overbrace{
    I_{ rs }
    \biggl[
    \mathrm{exp} \biggl(
    \frac{V + I R_{s}}{a \thinspace V_{t}}
    \biggl) - 1   
    \biggl]
    % overbrace title
}^{ I_{d} }
-
\overbrace{
    \frac{V + I R_{s}}{R_{p}}
    % overbrace title
}^{I_{p}}
%
\label{eq:I_PV_m}
\end{equation}



\begin{equation}
P_{e, \thinspace WT} =
    \left \{
        %
        \begin{aligned}
            %
            & 0  &   & v_{w} \thinspace < \thinspace v_{ci} 
            \\
            & P_{GCR} (v_{w}) \quad   & v_{ci} \thinspace \leq \thinspace &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{r} 
            \\
            & P_{r, \thinspace WT}   & v_{r} \thinspace \leq \thinspace  &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{co}
            \\
            & 0  &   & v_{w} > \thinspace v_{co}
            %
        \end{aligned}
    %
    \right.
%
\label{eq:WTPSC}
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation}
%
    \begin{aligned}
        %
        PMSE_{av} &= \frac{Mean \ Square \ Error}{Average \ of \ Estimations} \times 100\%
        \\
        & = \frac{ \displaystyle
            \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} {(x_{i}-y_{i})^2}
        }
        { \displaystyle
            \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} {y_{i}}
        } \times 100\%  
        %
    \end{aligned}
%
\label{eq:PMSE_av}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
```

Comment: mathspec is for unicode tex (xetex or luatex)  but your document is using T1 encoding which only makes sense if using an 8-bit tex such as pdftex.

Comment: It seems that the command is being ignored because I cannot see any difference whether it is there or not, but I used to put it when I was using pdftex.

Comment: math for 8bit tex requires multiple fonts in custom tex-specific encodings, each with 127 or 256 characters per font. math for unicode tex can use a single font with thousands of characters. the mechanisms and fonts used have almost nothing in common.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Although the single-font trick is usually `unicode-math` rather than `mathspec`, isn't it? Of course, `mathspec` still expects unicode fonts, but wouldn't you usually use it to combine stuff from multiple fonts?

Comment: @cfr with mathspec yes but basically any document that starts `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is unusable with xetex and probably will do the wrong thing in luatex, so I'm trying to find out what the actual use case is, this seems to be an X-Y question that's starting from the wrong point

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Your code appears to be trying to set an opentype font as the 'main maths font' and not one from PSNFSS. In addition, TeX Gyre Termes doesn't support Greek.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Definitely agree on that point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. If `T1` encoding only works with `pdfLaTeX`, how can someone use accents and get the font customization features of `XeLaTex` at the same time?

Comment: @cfr. My code is just a sample. I tried to replace `TeX Gyre Termes` with something like `ptm` but it did not work.

Comment: There's no problem using accents with XeLaTeX. You certainly don't need T1 for that - you are using a unicode encoding, which had slots for all the accented characters you could ever want (and many you never will).

Comment: The thing is, why are you trying to use `mathspec` if you want to use a PSNFSS font for maths? Just use a traditional configuration for maths and then load `fontspec` with `nomath` if you want to use opentype fonts for text mode.

Comment: if you use T1 with xetex then all hyphenation will be incorrect as xelatex does not load hyphenation tables for 8bit fonts. unicode forms as used by xetex of course support accents.

Comment: Then what kind of encoding would work well if I want to use `XeLaTeX` and be able to change math fonts?

Comment: for text fonts the only encoding to use with xetex is the default TU encoding. for math fonts you have a choice of unicode-math which will usie unicode math fonts or use classic math fonts or a kind of half-way which is mathspec which uses classic 8bit math fonts except using the unicode text fonts for math alphabets.

Comment: by coincidence this just became available https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MfY6EkiKc

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Use`mathastext` package under the following constraints:

1. load `mathastext` after loading all math font related packages
2. if you are using `fontspec` package then you must load it with the
   `no-math` option

`\MTDeclareVersion[<ltsh>]{<name>}{<enc>}{<fam>}{<ser>}{<sh>}`

This command declares the type of certain 'math version'

`<ltsh>`: shape of letters and small Greeks

`<name>`: name of the math font type being declared

`<enc>`: the needed encoding

`<fam>`: font family

`<ser>`: series type of the font

`<sh>`: shape of digits and capital Greeks

and

`\MTversion*{<name>}`

This command allows for the use of math version whose name is given in the mandatory argument.

- Example

`\MTDeclareVersion[it]{AvantGarde}{T1}{pag}{m}{n}` and `\MTversion*{AvantGarde}` give the math equation shown here

[image]

The equation above is shown only for reference.

**Long Answer**

`mathastext` package changes fonts used in math mode to virtually any font that can be used in text mode. Loading `mathastext`, as shown in its documentation, sets up a bigger size for subscripts hence. Using `defaultmathsizes` helps retain the default subscript sizes

- Important `mathastext` options:

`subdued`: allows `mathastext` to activate only by enabling math versions. Use this option along with `defaultmathsizes` to get displayed math to be almost as if `mathastext` had not been loaded

disables `mathastext`ification for `\mathxx` commands and enables them only after explicit `\MTversion` commands

IMPORTANT: if this option is enabled, it is highly recommended to explicitly set up and use a math version. Otherwise, unexpected results may appear in the font.

`italic`: specifies if math letters are italic by default (this does not affect greek letters unless `LGRgreek` is loaded and subdued is not)

`symbolgreek`: uses bold and upright Adobe Postscript Greek letters (it does not work if `LGRgreek` or `subdued` are active)

`eulergreek`: uses Greek letters from Euler font (it does not work if LGRgreek or subdued are active)

`LGRgreek`: uses bold and upright greek letter Adobe Postscript greek letters (it does not work if `LGRgreek` or subdued are active)

`itgreek` and `upgreek`: specifies whether small letter Greeks are in italic or upright shape

`itGreek` and `upGreek`: specifies whether capital letter Greeks are in italic or upright shape

`symbolmisc`: replaces older symbols with newer ones of better looks (e.x., thicker)

Compare the new ones

[image]

with the old ones

[image]

Also `symbolmisc` defines four new symbols

[image]

which can be accessed with `$\shortiff \longto \inftypsy \proptopsy$`

`symbolre`: redefines `\re` and `\im` to a better look

Compare the new ones

[image]

with the old ones

[image]

It also provides the `\DotTriangle` symbol

[image]

- Bold and italic styling commands `mathastext` commands

`\mathnormalbold{<exp>}`: provides a bold font for its argument
IMPORTANT: it is better to use this command instead of `\bm` since `\mathnormalbold` provides direct access to the bold version of `\mathnormal` and it is slightly more compact

[image]

`\MTmathoperatorsdonotobeymathxx`, `\MTnonlettersdonotobeymathxx`, and `\MTeasynonlettersdonotobeymathxx`

`\MTmathoperatorsdonotobeymathxx`: specifies that math operators (such as `sin`) will not obey math `\mathbf` or `\mathit`

`\MTnonlettersdonotobeymathxx`: specifies that math non-letters `(! ? , : ; + - = ( ) [ ] < >)` will not obey `\mathbf` or `\mathit` (default)

`\MTeasynonlettersdonotobeymathxx`: specifies that math easy nonletters `(. / | \ # $ % &)` do not obey `\mathbf` or `\mathit`

`\MTmathoperatorsobeymathxx`, `\MTnonlettersdonotobeymathxx`, and `\MTeasynonlettersobeymathxx`

`\MTmathoperatorsobeymathxx`: specifies that math operators (such as `sin`) will obey math `\mathbf` or `\mathit` (default)

`\MTnonlettersobeymathxx`: specifies that math non-letters `(! ? , : ; + - = ( ) [ ] < >)` will obey `\mathbf` or `\mathit` (when not used as delimiters with \left or \right)
% Important: this option may give raise to some compatibility issues with other packages

`\MTeasynonlettersobeymathxx`: specifies that math easy non-letters `(. / | \ # $ % &)` will obey `\mathbf` or `\mathit` (default)

Compare the default options:

[image]

with the non-default ones:

[image]

```
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\sin\left(x+y\right) = \left<\right> \cos(z-t)} / >
\\
&\mathbf{! \medspace ? \medspace , \medspace : \medspace ; \medspace + \medspace - \medspace = \medspace ( \medspace ) [ \medspace ] \medspace < \medspace >}
\\
& \mathbf{. \medspace / \medspace | \medspace \backslash \medspace \# \medspace \$ \medspace \% \medspace \&}
\end{align}


\MTmathoperatorsdonotobeymathxx

\MTnonlettersobeymathxx

\MTeasynonlettersdonotobeymathxx

\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}


\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\sin\left(x+y\right) = \left<\right> \cos(z-t)} / >
\\
&\mathbf{! \medspace ? \medspace , \medspace : \medspace ; \medspace + \medspace - \medspace = \medspace ( \medspace ) [ \medspace ] \medspace < \medspace >}
\\
& \mathbf{. \medspace / \medspace | \medspace \backslash \medspace \# \medspace \$ \medspace \% \medspace \&}
\end{align}
```

Comment: 8-bit fonts are like archaeology, like writing on paper instead of electronic. ASCII does not allow copy-paste to retain the semantic meaning of the symbols, e.g. all the alphabets in the  Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols unicode block. The author of the package mathastext says: "it is extremely far from being able to
define a math font, as it applies basically only to a subset of the 32-127 ascii range,
and in particular it does not know how to use a given Unicode font simultaneously
for Latin and Greek letters. Again the user is strongly advised to look at mathspec
and unicode-math."

Answer (score 1):

To use a `psnfss` font as the math font, load the relevant package, for example, `newtxmath` or `newpxmath`. You might need to use a package option to load only the math font. Then either load a text package of your choice, setting `fontenc` appropriately, or `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`.

You would load `mathspec` in order to set your math letters to an OpenType font, for example, AMS Euler but with italic letters from Palatino and digits from the text font. (Like with `eulerpx`, but using OpenType fonts.) You would use an OpenType or TrueType font with `\setmathsfont`, and not set `fontenc`.

Another option allowing you to use legacy text fonts in math mode is `mathastext`. The `isomath` package also has a comprehensive selection of font families as package options. As David Carslisle brings up in the comments, hyphenation might not work properly in xetex if you stick to NFSS text fonts.

However, my personal recommendation (Which some regulars with higher scores disagree with!) is to use `unicode-math` when you can, and legacy encodings only when you have to.