# Math typesetting with a given OpenType font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, mathspec, mathastext

## Hi!

**I am trying to typeset math with Arno Pro in LuaLaTeX.** However, I have not found a suitable solution yet. As Arno Pro does not have all the symbols required for proper math typesetting, some kind of workaround will be needed.

Included below are the two approaches I have tried while trying to answer this question.

## Solution 1 · `mathastext`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Compiling this MWE reveals that `mathastext` does not use Arno Pro's greek glyphs. Although `mathastext`’s documentation *does* have a section on a n option called `LGRgreek`, this option does not have any effect due to how `fontspec` handles Greek.

## Solution 2 · `unicode-math`

I will not reproduce what I tried out here, but what I tried was based off of [this infamous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238209/general-guide-on-how-to-set-up-minion-pro-for-math-in-lualatex). This has quite a few problems, and, as the answerer so aptly says, will ‘kill your time!’

Some problems I had were:

- Not respecting `Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}` (i.e. only respecting the one last in the `{ ... }`
- Many, many missing font feature errors (as Arno Pro does not have any math characters)

## Conclusion

In the end, all I am really looking for is a way to use an arbitrary font for some very basic math (just some basic algebra, arithmetic including roots and fractions, etc) that is well integrated both with `fontspec` (i.e. proportional text figures and other OpenType features are respected in math mode) and any Greek glyphs that may be present in the font. Come to think of it, this sound very similar to what `mathspec` provides.… It really is a shame that `mathspec` isn’t available in LuaLaTeX. If anyone knows a way to achieve my goal, I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: See this question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443095/how-can-i-set-a-font-from-psnfss-distribution-families-as-the-main-math-font

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a font from PSNFSS distribution families as the main math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443095/how-can-i-set-a-font-from-psnfss-distribution-families-as-the-main-math-font)

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh The linked question seems to be about `mathspec` which is not applicable here.

Comment: `mathastext` is of almost no use with OpenType fonts and Unicode engines. Its `LGRgreek` option as its name indicate is for using "`256-slots for TeX fonts`" in LGR encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have Arno Pro available, so I used the free Crimson instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Crimson}

% Set baseline math font (Crimson goes well with Pagella)
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% Get alphabets from text font
\setmathfont[range={up}]{Crimson-Roman.otf}
\setmathfont[range={it}]{Crimson-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont[range={bfup}]{Crimson-Bold.otf}
\setmathfont[range={bfit}]{Crimson-BoldItalic.otf}
% Restore the broken symbols (if there are none, just use range={})
\setmathfont[range={\partial}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also use `mathspec` in LuaTeX with the [`XeTeXemulate`](https://gist.github.com/hmenke/6e8ff7c90a5e5df3c4895f60059a2ef7#file-xetexemulate-sty) pacakge.  Download the linked file [`XeTeXemulate.sty`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hmenke/6e8ff7c90a5e5df3c4895f60059a2ef7/raw/834696380b11064b608ea20d33eb9de42acf7bf7/XeTeXemulate.sty) and place it in the same directory as your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XeTeXemulate}
\XeTeXemulate
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Crimson}

\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. I didn't know absolutely `\blindmathpaper`. It is very interesting.