# Installing MinionPro Mac OSX

Tags: typography, mac, minionpro

This question seems to be everywhere but none of the solutions are working for me.

I am following the github: https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro

I do the following

- Move my .otf files into a directory /otf/
- Run `./scripts/makeall MinionPro`
- Run `./scripts/install $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)`
- Run `updmap --enable Map=MinionPro.map`

Final output is:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /Users/Jack/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /Users/Jack/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/Users/Jack/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

**My Error**

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+382/600 --dpi 382 MinionPro-Regular-osf-l1-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for MinionPro-Regular-osf-l1-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps MinionPro-Regular-osf-l1-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular-osf-l1-t1--
base): Font MinionPro-Regular-osf-l1-t1--base at 382 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

My example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    a = (b + c) = \big( a + b \big)
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

**Edit** More verbose error from TeXShop added

Comment: Really /otf/? What otf fonts do you have?

Comment: @HerbSchulz In FontPro I make the dir `otf` as required

My four fonts from Adobe are
`MinionPro-Bold.otf, MinionPro-BoldIt.otf, MinionPro-It.otf, MinionPro-Regular.otf`

Comment: I really don't want to spoil the fun, but if you have the otf fonts, then why not using them directly in `lualatex` or `xelatex`...

Comment: @DG As far as I'm aware, MinionPro also includes some additional kerning for the maths. This is why I am trying to use the package.

Comment: My concern is that when installing something has gone into a wrong folder and my maps are badly configured.

Is there a way to basically wipe all textmf and start again?

I tried using this, but it did not fix the error: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i

Comment: Check the [`install` script](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/blob/master/scripts/install) and look where it puts stuff in the TDS and delete it then. For what it's worth, try this script: https://github.com/chapter09/Install-MinionPro

Comment: Have you tried that script @DG'? Thanks for the link

Comment: I think I did, many years ago. But I don't think, it's worth the trouble. Find some good [open type math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available/425099#425099) and go with `lualatex`. Or use Open Type in math: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448937/29873

Comment: Which engine you are using? It is much easy in `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` compared to `PDFLaTeX`

Answer (score 3):

Just want to say that the script DG shared: https://github.com/chapter09/Install-MinionPro

When run against a clean install of MacTex ran without errors and `\usepackage{MinionPro}` runs with no errors.

I cannot determine the root of the issue I had with FontPro though

Answer (score 1):

Under macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) and using MacTeX 2020, I have encountered the same kind of problem, regardless of the implemented method. I have tried to install the font following:

- the `README` file from Ctan's MinionPro page;
- the tips found in [answers to this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251748/installing-minionpro-font-on-latex-some-problems);
- the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) script and related instructions;
- the script from https://github.com/chapter09/Install-MinionPro;
- all of these methods all over again on a clean install each time.

In my case the error is very similar, but the name of the missing file and number changes for each method:

```
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular-...(DIFFERENT FILE EACH TIME)...-
base): Font MinionPro-Regular-...(DIFFERENT FILE EACH TIME)... at (DIFFERENT NUMBER EACH TIME) not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The only thing that worked, was adding the following line in the preamble as indicated in the answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55881/local-font-installation-problems):

```
\pdfmapfile{=MinionPro.map}
```

This seems to work with both the FontPro and the script from https://github.com/chapter09/Install-MinionPro (did not further test the official procedure).